# How can I use UpSet with a derivative value?

Tags: replacement

I'm trying to `UpSet` a certain value for the derivative of a function $Y=Y(l,m,x)$.
This can be done by:

```
D[Y[l_, m_, x_], x_] ^= (l + 1) Y[l, m, x];
D[Y[a, b, c], c]
(*(1 + a) Y[a, b, c]*)
```

But the problem is, this doesn't always work since for other types of expressions, because Mathematica uses a different form:

```
D[c *Y[a, b, c], c]
(*Y[a,b,c]+c (Y^(0,0,1))[a,b,c]*)
```

I've tried solving this with another `UpSet`, but I get an error.

```
(Y^(0,0,1))[a_,b_,c_] ^= (l+1) Y[l,m,x]
```

[image: error].

How can I solve this?

Comment: I did, still the same error if I want to match the arugments.
Of course somethings lie `Derivative[0,0,1][Y][a,b,c]^= (a+1) Y[a,b,c]` works, but only if I use the correct arguments. I want to be able to use any arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
Derivative[0, 0, 1][Y][l_, m_, x_] := (l + 1) Y[l, m, x]
D[c*Y[a, b, c], c]
(*Y[a, b, c] + (1 + a) c Y[a, b, c]*)
```